# html5 canvas drawing / saving

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm attempting to turn the html5 canvas into a slide annotator. My goal is to upload an Image of a slide, allow the user to draw on it, and then save it.

Whats working: I successfully have slides being uploaded as background images and allowing the user to draw on them. I also have the save function working.

Whats wrong: Once the image is save, the drawing the user made stays but the background image doesn't become part of the saved image.

Is there a way to save the canvas to an image and keep the slide background in it? Perhaps its not supposed to be a background image?

Here is some of my code:

The Canvas + button:

```
<div id="main">
<canvas id="drop1" class="drop" style="  background: url(pdf_images/pdf-save-0.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
</canvas>
</div>

<input type="button" id="savepngbtn" value="Save Slide">
```

Saving the Canvas:

```
document.getElementById("savepngbtn").onclick = function() {
        saveCanvas(oCanvas, "PNG");
    }

function saveCanvas(pCanvas, strType) {
        var bRes = false;
        if (strType == "PNG")
            bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
        if (!bRes) {
            alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to make the 'background-image' part of the canvas if you would like to save them as a single image.

you can try something like:

```
var ctx = yourcanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://yourimage.png';
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
}
```

then allow the user to add the annotations and save.

Comment: How do I go about doing that differently from how I already have done it?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a background image.

You should use the canvas's provided `DrawImage` to draw an image. It's pretty simple to do so, just create a new image element (ie. `new Image()`, set the `onload` event to call `DrawImage` with itself as a parameter and then set the `.src` attribute so that it actually loads).

Obviously this should be the first thing you do as the image is kindof paramount to how the canvas works. You could add an additional hook within `onload` so as to not allow the user to do any drawing until the image has loaded.